# How to create Log files separately for PJSUA app running?

Tags: ios, sip, voip, pjsip, pjsua2

I have an iOS Voip app that uses pjsua. And I have to write all logs coming from pjsua to the file, but I don't know how and where to start. Can anyone help me?

Comment: When you done this log creation in your pjsua application successfully, please leave an answer here, that how to create  log files.

Comment: please leave an answer below for how to create logs for pjsua app and where to create. give any suggestion please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To write logs from pjsua to file we have to define optional property log_filename of app_config structure for app_init function:

```
     /* logFileName is a constant of pj_str_t type.*/
     pj_str_t logFileName = pj_str("/Users/user/Documents/logfile.log")
     /* Public API */ 
     pj_status_t app_init(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        //Optional log filename if app wishes the library to write to log file.
                    app_config.log_cfg.log_filename = logFileName;
     }
```

Comment: I tried this many times. But no logs has been written into the file. In which method and in which file we want to add this above lines. please reply to solve this problem.

Comment: where do you call app_init()? 
try to specify arguments for this function like app_init(int argc, char *argv[], pj_str_t logFileName) for UserAgent class as global variable and for forpjsua_app.c and when you call this function u can specify file name then before calling

Comment: and don't forget    app_config.log_cfg.log_filename = logFileName:

Comment: I have added successfully. But where the file will created when app is running on iphone

Comment: NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    path = [paths.firstObject stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Logs"];

Comment: and then something like that:     NSString *full = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

Comment: By the above code, where the log file is created @dasha either in iphone or in any server path

Comment: its created in iPhone

Comment: Can we add a log files in servers while the app is running ?

Comment: yes, it has to be rest or rpc request, etc. it's another topic: how to write file to the server or so